# USB between Teensy and Windows PC speed improvements

Tags: python, serial-port, usb, usbserial

I am working on a project that involves a PC app (python, QT) is communicating over USB to a Teensy 4.1 and is taking longer than I'd expect to talk.

Right now I estimate the travel time is somewhere > 1ms to transfer 5 bytes, despite using the USB protocol which should be transferring extremely fast.

my connection in the PC app looks like (baud rate should be ignored with USB protocol):

```
ser_handle = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=9600, writeTimeout=1, timeout=3)
```

and it writes like:

```
self.ser_handle.write("1234\n".encode())
```

On the Teensy side, we read serial like so:

```
void Serial_Receive() {
  char incoming_byte;  
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incoming_byte = Serial.read();
    rx_buffer.concat(incoming_byte);
    if (incoming_byte == '\n') {
       stringlen = rx_buffer.length();
    }    
  }
}
```

Once we get a newline char, we will exit this function and process the data.
Assuming our loop speed is extremely fast, does this make sense?

Basically looking for any glaring issues that might be the cause of really slow data speeds. Are there any drivers/protocols/setup that needs to be done have USB serial work faster between the PC and teensy?

Comment: The fact that it is USB shouldn't matter. The BAUD rate is 9600 bps. That's about 1.2 bytes/ms. So 5 bytes should take about 6ms. You could try a faster baud rate, like 115200.

Comment: @001 If it's a serial emulator, not a real serial port, why would the baud rate be obeyed?

Comment: You're not using the raw USB protocol, but probably the Teensy is a CDC ACM device. Instead of making assumptions, figure out what you actually have. See https://github.com/TeensyUser/doc/wiki/Serial BTW your liberal use of subjective speeds (such as "*extremely fast*" and "*really slow*") and only one vague quantitative estimate (i.e. "*somewhere > 1ms*") is problematic. Your "problem" seems to be based on perception and some kind of expectation, rather than any actual measurements.

Comment: What exactly did you measure that is taking 1 ms, and how did you measure it?  Your code looks fine and it's not likely you can improve it significantly, so you're probably just seeing a little bit of normal overhead from the OS.  Switching to Linux might improve it.  If you send larger chunks of data you should see much higher transfer speeds in terms of bytes per second.

Comment: We need to send 1 data packet at a time because each event that would warrant a new data packet is time sensitive. Single events need to be very fast through the pipeline.

Comment: We have a system that timing is extremely important for a single event. I trigger a camera and once a camera callback function is called I print the time.time() as an and print the time.time() as soon as serial.write() is called to teensy. I measure this at about 2 ms. However, the total event time is more accurately measured by the teensy, which says that the event is actually active for 3.4 ms. 

So i figured one avenue could be the serial writing being slow. The other could be reading an image sensor... maybe that is slower than I think. Its a small 700x200 8-bit sensor though